# Question on Query execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-execution-plan

In the below query if the Patients table has 1000 records how many times TableValueFunction executes? Only once or 1000 time?

This is a query in a Stored Procedure, do you have a better idea to improve this?

```
SELECT * FROM Patients
WHERE Patient.Id In (SELECT PatientId FROM TableValueFunction(parameters..))
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that it will only get executed once.  However I suggest you check using the "show execution plan" option in SQL Server Management Studio.  Without knowing what the TableValueFunction does we can't really tell you if there is a better way.

Comment: Are you talking about a multi statement TVF or an inline TVF?

Comment: @ Martin : It's a inline TVF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you are using as parameters. If the parameters are constants the function will execute one time but if the parameters are fields from `Patients` the function will execute as many times as there are rows in table `Patients`.

Comment: +1 Thank you! Parameters are constants. Could you please explain how it caches the result if it executes only once? Cache per transaction?

Comment: @CharithJ - Chances are that the TVF will be used as the driving input to a nested loops join so it doesn't need to cache any results. Each row will be processed as it comes out to seek into the Patients table. Or maybe as the build input to a hash join  If you were to join the TVF to itself however it might execute multiple times or you might see a spool in the plan to cache results.

Answer (score 1):

To some extent it depends on whether you are talking about an inline TVF or a multi statement one.

A multi statement TVF is totally opaque to the query optimiser. It always assumes that it will return 1 row and it will not get expanded out into the main query.

Because of the 1 row assumption then if your Patients table is indexed on `PatientId` you will probably get a nested loops join with the TVF as the driving table meaning that it is only executed once.

If it is not indexed and you get a hash or merge join both of these methods only process both inputs once.

An inline TVF gets merged into the query itself. So the function itself is never executed as such. However SQL Server can then refer to cardinality information and might order the plan such that the query contained in the TVF appears on the inner side of a nested loops join and has a number of executions greater than one.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the explanation, it's a Inline TVF. So hopefully executes only once...